# Pass extra argument to IntersectionObserver?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, intersection-observer

How would I pass an extra argument to the IntersectionObserver? I am trying to create a lazyload plugin for Vue. It works fine like this but I also want to be able to call a provided directive function.

```
const lazyload = {
    install(Vue) {
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
            entries.forEach((entry) => {
                if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
                    console.log('In viewport');
                }
            });
        });

        Vue.directive('lazy', {
            inserted(element) {
                observer.observe(element);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

This would mean that in the inserted function I would set `binding` as the second argument.

```
inserted(element, binding)
```

How would I pass this binding though so that I could use it within my IntersectionObserver callback?

In the end it should be able to look something like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-6" v-lazy="fire">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could access the directive's arguments with [`binding.value`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Directive-Hook-Arguments):

```
// html
<div v-lazy="0.5"></div>

// script
Vue.directive('lazy', {
  inserted(el, binding) {
    console.log(binding.value) // 0.5
  }
})
```

It probably makes sense to create a new `IntersectionObserver` for each directive usage. For instance, you might want one `div` to have a different scroll threshold from another `div`. Within the `inserted` callback, I would create the observer with options specified in the directive arguments:

```
const makeObserver = options => new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    console.log({entry, ratio: options.threshold})
    if (entry.intersectionRatio >= options.threshold) {
      console.log('In viewport', {entry, ratio: options.threshold});
    }
  });
}, options);

Vue.directive('lazy', {
  inserted(el, binding) {
    const options = binding.value || {}
    const observer = makeObserver(options)
    observer.observe(el)
  }
})
```

Then, you could use that directive to create multiple `div`s with different parameters for `IntersectionObserver`:

```
<div style="height: 100px; background: gray" v-lazy="{root: null, threshold: 0.1}"></div>
<div style="height: 200px; background: lightgray" v-lazy="{root: null, threshold: 1}"></div>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/qpMYEy?editors=1011)

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to pass the values as an extra argument you could use [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), but you'd have to create a separate IntersectionObserver for each directive invocation.

I'd recommend a WeakMap here, and have the callback check the map for the proper handler. Something like:

```
const lazyload = {
  install(Vue) {
    const handlers = new WeakMap();
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
      entries.forEach((entry) => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          console.log('In viewport');
          handlers.get(entry.target)();
        }
      });
    });

    Vue.directive('lazy', {
      inserted(element, binding) {
        handlers.set(element, binding.value);
        observer.observe(element);
      }
    });
  }
};
```

(I haven't used Vue, so I'm not sure this will work verbatim)

As an aside, I changed `entry.intersectionRatio > 0` to `entry.isIntersecting`. This might be a bug, but I've seen in Chrome 65 that when scrolling very slowly, you can get `entry.intersectionRatio === 0 && entry.isIntersecting === true`: https://jsfiddle.net/3jgm0ch7/2/